# How can I list all the database roles for a user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to list one specific user's all mapping databases and all its database roles.

e.g. this user " 566vm/administrator" ,it mapps database "TEST" and "test2" and the database role membership for TEST are "dbowner" and "public"; for test2 are "dbowner" and "public"
[image]